# Genetic Algorithm Constraints

Tags: matlab, genetic-algorithm

How can I pass the following constraints to the Matlab `ga` optimization function? Note that `x` is a vector `1xnvars`

#### Constraint 1

```
0.2 <= sum(x,2)/(W*H) <= 0.4 

where `W` and `H` are two constant.
```

#### Constraint 2

```
x(1) >= x(2) >= ... >= x(size(x,1))
```

Comment: Is it `sum(x,2)/W*H` or `sum(x,2)/(W*H)` ?

Comment: @Nishant Sorry, is `sum(x,2)/(W*H)` my bad!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer [here](http://www.mathworks.in/help/gads/ga.html) for the documentation.

```
A = cat(1,ones(1,nvars), ones(1,nvars)*-1)/W/H;
b = [0.4;-0.2];    

function [ceq ce] = noncolon1(x)
    ce = [];
    ceq = x(1,2:end) - x(1,1:end-1);
end

[x , fval] = ga(@fitnessfunc,nvars,A,b,[],[],[],[],@noncolon1);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. Is there any chance to pass the constraints to ga before the evaluation of the solutions? I mean, I need to "reduce" the number of solutions to be evaluate according to these two constraints in order to achieve a lower computational time.

Comment: I could not understand you question. What you want is actually what `ga` does.

Comment: I thought that using constraints i'll be able to compute the problema faster, but the computational time is 3 times the initial one :)

Comment: constraints are not meant to compute faster , they are meant to get desired results. And computation time in `ga` depends much on your `fitness function`.